# Use EWS to access mails stored in Archive folder in Exchange 365

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In Exchange 365, there is now the ability to archive an email after you have read it.

[image]

Once you click the 'Archive' button the email is moved out of the users Inbox into an Archive folder.

I am trying to access the mails in this Archive folder using EWS but have not had any luck.

The Archive folder does not appear in the `WellKnownFolderName` enum. The closest options `ArchiveRoot` or `ArchiveMsgFolderRoot` generate an error when I try to access them

```
{"The specified folder could not be found in the store."}   System.Exception {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException}
```

The 'In-Place Archive' feature is disabled for this mailbox in the Exchange Admin area.

I have also tried to EWS `AutodiscoverService` Service to find any alternative mailboxes assigned to the target user but no mailboxes are returned.

Can someone please outline how I can use EWS to read mails from this Archive Folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder is your screenshot is just a normal Mailbox Folder (user created) so you would need to find that folder eg something like

```
        FindFoldersResults aFolders = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot,new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName,"Archive"), new FolderView(1));
        if(aFolders.Folders.Count == 1){

        }
```

Should work okay. The actual feature your using in this instance is called One-Click Archive https://blogs.office.com/2015/08/04/new-features-coming-to-outlook-on-the-web/ (its just a move so not a true a archive in the conventional sense unless the some other process hooked to the folder

ArchiveRoot or ArchiveMsgFolderRoot are of the InPlace Archive

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet - that did the trick.  When the user clicks on this Archive button for the first time, they are prompted where they would like to store the archive mail - in a default folder called Archive or a folder of their choice. If they pick a custom folder, do you know if there is any way to programatically find the name of this folder via EWS? Basically I would like to always be able to find mails in their Archive folder - no matter what one they have chosen.

Comment: Not that I know off they haven't documented where the configuration for that is stored and when you do set it this doesn't seem to trigger any Item updates or creates that i can see in a Mailbox.

Comment: I'm late to the party, late learning EWS API (with PowerShell for me), but this snippet helped me to see the way.  Nice, slick, and short.